# Is there any problem when reading a char that is inside a struc?

Tags: c, struct, char, scanf

So I have this code and for some reason when I am trying to enter all the "requested" information, my program always skips scanning the char

Currently I solved it by creating a char type variable with an array on 1 position and treating it as a string, but it doesn't make sense why it wont read a char

```
struct person
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
    char sex;
};

int main()
{
    struct person data[3];

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        printf("\nType in the data of the person number: %d",i+1);
        printf("\nName: ");
        scanf("%s",data[i].name);
        printf("\nAge: ");
        scanf("%d",&data[i].age);
        printf("\nSex (M/F): ");
        scanf("%c",data[i].sex);
    }
}
```

It perfectly scans name and age, it even prints them, but for some reason, it refuses to scan the sex

Comment: `scanf("%c",data[i].sex);` -->         `scanf("%c",&data[i].sex);`

Comment: @kiranBiradar *`scanf("%c",&data[i].sex);`* *~>* `scanf(" %c", &data[i].sex);`

Answer (score 2):

The `char` gets read but it is the newline character `'\n'` left from the previous `scanf()`. To skip leading whitespace use

```
scanf(" %c", &data[i].sex);
//     |
//     +---- skips leading whitespace
```

And you also missed the address-of operator in your code.

The leading space is not necessary for most format specifiers like `%d` because they skip leading whitespace per default.

Answer (score 0):

There is a newline character in your input stream, which is read as the character (`%c`) you're trying to read as gender.

You can read this character and ignore it in this way:

```
        printf("\nSex (M/F): ");
        getchar();  //ignore the remained character in input stream
        scanf("%c", &data[i].sex);
```

As mentioned in other answers, you also have forgotten the reference symbol (`&`) in scanning the gender.